# What are recommended clearances for a portable electrical generator?

Tags: generator

What are the recommended clearances for a gasoline or natural gas powered portable electrical generator, on all sides and top and bottom?  The generator is about 5,000 watts.

Comment: I would imagine the manufacturer has specific recommendations in the manual for the generator, as it will also partially depend on where the exhaust and air intakes are located. Since you're saying "all sides" does this mean you're also intending to put it inside a structure of some sort? This may invoke fire and/or other building codes, depending on your jurisdiction.

Comment: What is the make and model of the generator?

Comment: @Tester101 I am considering the Honda 3000is and a tri fuel (to run on Nat Gas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general advice seems to be

- 3 feet (1 meter) from buildings, equipment, and combustible materials.
- 10 feet away from bystanders, children, and pets.

But the only way to know for sure, is to read the manufacturer's documentation for your specific unit.

---

This [service manual](http://www.subarupower.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/subaru-generators-commercial-sgx3500-sgx5000-sgx7500e-owners.pdf) says "*Keep the generator at least 1 meter (3 feet) away, including overhead, from any structure...*"

> [image]

This [owner's manual](http://cdn.powerequipment.honda.com/pe/pdf/manuals/00X31Z236000.pdf) says "*Operate generator at least 3 feet (1 meter) away from buildings and other equipment.*"

> [image]

This [operator's manual](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/1f/1f6fc9fb-0aa5-4ec3-ac9e-0bc93873ce15.pdf) says "*Keep the generator a minimum of 3 feet away from all types of combustible material.*"

> [image]

and also says "*Keep all bystanders, children, and pets at least 10 feet away.*"

> [image]